# ternary expression in ng-click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a ternary expression in the ng-click attribute. **I don't want to use a separate controller function if possible**.

It's a two button toggle setup - I can get a simple toggle working, but don't want a second click of the "off" button to turn back on.

The ternary in ng-click does not work (note the ternary in ng-class does work):

```
<button
    ng-click="allOn2==true ? allOn2 : !allOn2"
    ng-class="allOn2==true ? 'btn-green-on' : 'btn-green-off'">
ON</button>
```

Here's a more complete jsfiddle:
[toggler](http://jsfiddle.net/braddo/DUJrX/13/)

Comment: Why not just use ng-switch?

Comment: Haven't learned about ng-switch yet but from a brief check it seems more like a multi-choice ng-show/hide. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not doing anything with the ternary expression. For it to be useful, assign it:

```
{{ var1 }} {{ var2}}
<button
    ng-click="var1 = (allOn2==true ? allOn2 : !allOn2)"
    ng-class="{'btn-green-on':allOn2, 'btn-green-off' : !allOn2}">
ON</button>
```

I'm not sure how you can use ternary expressions for ng-class though...

Comment: Ah... you're right. My fiddle doesn't show any ng-model to which I have bound the value of allOn, as in my project. But I can see why what you suggested works. I think I was confused becuase the ng-class requires you to "do nothing" i.e. just evaluate the expression to find the class. I need to have the on-click set the value of allOn explicitly, which I thought was just happening through evaluation of the expression. Thanks!

Comment: here's a link to the updated fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/braddo/DUJrX/16/)

Comment: Checking for a boolean value in a ternary is kind of redundant. `allOn2==true ? allOn2 : !allOn2` can just be `allOn2 = !allOn2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something as as a workaround for ternary

```
 ng-click="(AppliedApps!=null && Collapse('CollapsedAppliedApplications')) || 
(AppliedApps.length==0 && Collapse('CollapsedAppliedApplications'))">
```